# Synchronous instantiation pattern -- flat JSON to actual, circular data structure?

Tags: javascript, json, design-patterns, instantiation, synchronous

JSON comes in with many object descriptions

These objects hold **string** references to other objects in this flat structure

Currently, we instantiate all objects and just retain the **string** references to other objects

I want the instances to have actual, **object** references to the other instances

---

Is there any simple pattern for iterating this initial JSON in a synchronous manner?

Currently, we're essentially using `forEach` and `new Class` with each description

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Ok I think I figured it out

The answer is to create a registering function, which specifies a dep is missing

`pend(id, dependentObject, dependentProp) {}`

Knowing that all JSON objects will be iterated: upon iterating and constructing an object, check that another object is pending for that id, and assign `dependentObject[dependentProp] = instance`, which was previously registered with `pend(...)`

By the end of iteration, all deps should be met, even if they didn't exist initially